# Flutter showing error while building ios?

Tags: ios, dart, flutter, cocoapods

=== BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
    Swift 3 mode has been deprecated and will be removed in a later version of
    Xcode. Please migrate "Runner" to Swift 4.2 using "Convert > To Current
    Swift Syntax…" in the Edit menu.
    Swift 3 mode has been deprecated and will be removed in a later version of
    Xcode. Please migrate "Runner" to Swift 4.2 using "Convert > To Current
    Swift Syntax…" in the Edit menu.
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
    --path/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:
    6:9: fatal error: 'connectivity/ConnectivityPlugin.h' file not found
    #import 
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.

flutter doctor:

```
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.3.11-pre.10, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

xcode version: 10

and I'm fixing bugs of my old project

Comment: please 1. run flutter doctor (and give us the output) 2. let us know the xcode version you are using. 3 are you building some old ios project?

Comment: This error is due to some version issue it can be solved by creating the new project and migrating all the project code to the new project.

Comment: Have you tried actually opening the runner project and concerting to the new syntax as it is mentioned ?

Comment: In my case, the wrong target was selected.

Answer (score 2):

1-In Xcode >> open Product menu >> then choose  clean

2-While you are in iOS folder open terminal and run `pod install`

Reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21989#issuecomment-509193686

Comment: thanks worked for me, I also added the connectivity package on windows and got the error when trying to upload it to App Store with the Mac

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue from last week. I search a lot but I didn't find anything helpful.I follow the below step to build IPA:

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

I was trying to build IPA using projectPath/ios/Runner.xcodeproj in xcode which was wrong and throwing this error "connectivity/ConnectivityPlugin.h' file not found".

How to solve problem:

1) Close xCode.

2) Install or update POD in projectPath/ios/ using terminal.

3) ProjectPath/ios/Runner.xcworkspace open it using xCode.

4) On top menu of xCode go to Product and click on Archive.

5) To see IPA goto Top menu of xCode => Window and click on Orginazer.

Note: Nothing need to be changed in project code. Pod install/Update required.

**And after successfully build IPA from projectPath/ios/Runner.xcworkspace I opened projectPath/ios/Runner.xcodeproj again and I was seeing this error. So according to my knowledge ignore this error in Runner.xcodeproj**

Answer (score 2):

The solution worked for me is as follows.

First do `flutter clean`

then goto `projectDirectory/ios` and open the `Runner.xcworkspace` file instead of `Runner.xcodeproject`

Then go to `Product` menu in the opened xcode window and click on on Archive/Build as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** First do `flutter clean`

**2.** Secondly do `flutter build ios`

this is automtically run the `pod install`.